# will Ubuntu touch support Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-touch

Will it be possible to install Virtualbox on a future tablet with Ubuntu Touch, so that some needed Windows programs could be run?

Comment: if you need to run a windows program, install wine and you can run windows programs on ubuntu without virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

from an open terminal to see if this is possible.

0 means no and 1+ means yes

You may still be able to run a virtual machine if the answer is no but it will run really slow.

[see here for more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)

---

If you want to run windows programs on ubuntu, just install wine and you won't need virtualization.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Right click on the exe file and choose to run with wine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can only be it depends on the tablet hardware. If the tablet is x86 based then yes, you will be able to use wine or VirtualBox. If it is arm-based then the most likely answer is no.

You should be able to run a x86 emulator in arm, but it'll be too slow to run windows programs, and you'll be able to run some arm Windows apps through wine but this is not probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "**does (the usual ARM) Ubuntu Touch device support running typical x86/64bit Windows applications through Wine**"?

The short answer is: no. Wine is not about emulating CPU architecture, but about translating Windows system/library calls into Linux system/library calls. [But instead you will be able to run natively ARM Windows applications](https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM)

If the application is old enough and 32bit, you can run it on DOSBox ([DOSBox supports Windows 95](https://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=3120&letter=W), but you need to [install it yourself](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hvgFvAYjPG93h-Avun3sprvZX2GfkRhl4YJBT15FTx0/edit)). DOSBox is an x86 emulator.

(I will definitely try this when I buy the promised MEIZU 6 Ubuntu Touch)